# Error when trying to access second page of paginated table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, pagination

I have a paginated table in an ASP .Net Core MVC app where the first "page" of the table is correctly displaying the amount of table rows as specified. The issue is that when the "next" button is pressed to send the asynchronous call to the controller action to get the next set of rows, the server isn't able to find the controller action.

I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and as it outlines, the following code should be used for the page links in the view (modified for use in this case):

```
  @{ 
        var prevDisabled = !Model.PageList.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var nextDisabled = !Model.PageList.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
        }

    <a asp-action="GetResultList"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]" 
       asp-route-page="@(Model.PageList.PageIndex - 1)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
        Previous
    </a>
    <a asp-action="GetResultList"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
       asp-route-page="@(Model.PageList.PageIndex + 1)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
        Next
    </a>
```

The link in the url when the form is initially loaded is `http://localhost:62501/Home/..%2FresortDeals%2FGetResultList` but when the "next" button is clicked, the url is: `http://localhost:62501/resortDeals/GetResultList?page=2`

This is strange because the asp action for the submit button of the form has the same value:

```
 <div>
            <input type="submit" value="View Results" asp-action="GetResultList" class="btn btn-sm" />
        </div>
```

I'm assuming the issue might have to do with the value for the page parameter specified in `asp-route-page` but I'm not sure exactly why it might cause for there to be a vastly different url to be used as I'm still very new to using tag helpers. **What could be causing the "next" button be generating the incorrect url?**

### Edit

**controller action:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetResultList(ResortDataJoinObj resDeals, int page =1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var resultsObj = (from rd in _db.ResortData
                                  join ra in _db.ResortAvailability on rd.RecNo equals ra.RecNoDate
                                  where ra.TotalPrice < Int32.Parse(resDeals.priceHighEnd) && ra.TotalPrice > Int32.Parse(resDeals.priceLowEnd)

                                  select new ResortDealResultsObject
                                  {
                                      Name = rd.Name,
                                      ImageUrl = rd.ImageUrl,
                                      ResortDetails = rd.ResortDetails,
                                      CheckIn = ra.CheckIn,
                                      Address = rd.Address,
                                      TotalPrice = ra.TotalPrice

                                  });
                int i = 0;
                List<ResortDealResultsObject> resultList = new List<ResortDealResultsObject>();
                foreach (var row in resultsObj)
                {
                        var tempVm = new ResortDealResultsObject
                        {
                            Name = row.Name,
                            ImageUrl = row.ImageUrl,
                            ResortDetails = row.ResortDetails,
                            CheckIn = row.CheckIn,
                            Address = row.Address,
                            TotalPrice = row.TotalPrice
                        };
                        resultList.Add(tempVm);
                }
                int pageSize = 3;    
                var model = await PaginatedList<ResortDealResultsObject>.CreateAsync(resultsObj, page, pageSize);
                ResortDataJoinObj joinObj = new ResortDataJoinObj();
                joinObj.PageList = model;
                ViewBag.rowsReturned = true;

                return View(joinObj);
            }
            return View(resDeals);
        }
```

**HTML Form:**

```
<form asp-action="GetResultList" method="post">
        <div>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label asp-for="ResData.Name"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ResData.Name" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ResData.Name"></span>
                    </div>
                    @*<div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label asp-for="ResAvail.CheckIn"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ResAvail.CheckIn" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ResAvail.CheckIn"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label asp-for="ResAvail.CheckOut"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ResAvail.CheckOut" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ResAvail.CheckOut"></span>
                        </div>*@
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="priceLowEnd"></label>
                        <input asp-for="priceLowEnd" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="priceLowEnd"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label asp-for="priceHighEnd"></label>
                        <input asp-for="priceHighEnd" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="priceHighEnd"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="ResData.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="View Results" asp-action="GetResultList" class="btn btn-sm" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: why did you have `asp-action` on a submit button? It should be on the form, shouldn't it? Also with just the code you posted, it's very hard to know what's going on. At least you should show the `Controller` as well?

Comment: @DavidLiang Right, I updated the post with the code from the controller action as well as the html form.

Comment: I see you're using `POST` method on the form. In the guide you referred, `GET` is used.

Comment: @DavidLiang I removed the `[HttpPost]` tag from the controller action. Is that the best way to fix the issue?

Comment: Usually for pagination, you should just have a controller action to have a parameter `page=1`, like what you had, to indicate the current page selection. And on the pagination item links, you can get the current url and change that `page` parameter to `currentPage + - 1`, `currentPage + - 2`, etc. You shouldn't need to use form submission for pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me re-state what I said in the comment:

> Usually for pagination, you should just have a controller action to have a parameter `page=1`, like what you had, to indicate the current page selection. And on the pagination item links, you can get the current url and just change the `page` parameter to `currentPage +/- 1`, `currentPage +/- 2`, etc.

So I will do pagination like the following:

#### Create a class, `Pager.cs`, to represent the logic

```
using System;

namespace DL.SO.Framework.Mvc.Pagination
{
    public class Pager
    {
        // Here I hard code the page size but you can set it as one of
        // the parameters of its constructor
        private const int PAGESIZE = 12;

        public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public int StartPage { get; private set; }
        public int EndPage { get; private set; }

        public int PageSize
        {
            get { return PAGESIZE; }
        }

        public int ShowingRangeFromItem
        {
            get
            {
                int fromItem = (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize + 1;
                if (fromItem > TotalItems)
                {
                   fromItem = TotalItems;
                }

                return fromItem;
            }
        }

        public int ShowingRangeToItem
        {
            get
            {
                int toItem = CurrentPage * PageSize;
                if (toItem > TotalItems)
                {
                    toItem = TotalItems;
                }

                return toItem;
            }
        }

        // Constructor
        public Pager(int totalItems, int currentPage = 1)
        {
            // Calculate total, start and end pages
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)PageSize);

            currentPage = currentPage < 1
                ? 1
                : currentPage;

            // I only want to display +/- 2 pagination links
            var startPage = currentPage - 2;
            var endPage = currentPage + 2;

            if (startPage <= 0)
            {
                endPage = endPage - startPage + 1;
                startPage = 1;
            }

            if (endPage > totalPages)
            {
                endPage = totalPages;
                if (endPage > 5)
                {
                    startPage = endPage - 4;
                }
            }

            TotalItems = totalItems;
            CurrentPage = currentPage;
            TotalPages = totalPages;
            StartPage = startPage;
            EndPage = endPage;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Create a partial view, `_PagerPartial.cshtml`, in Shared folder for constructing the pagination

```
@model DL.SO.Framework.Mvc.Pagination.Pager

@if (Model != null && Model.TotalItems > 0)
{
   <div class="list-pager">
       <div class="list-pager-info">
           <span>
               Showing 
               <strong>@Model.ShowingRangeFromItem-@Model.ShowingRangeToItem</strong>
               of
               <strong>@Model.TotalItems</strong>
               entries
           </span>
       </div>
       <div class="list-pagination">
           <ul class="pagination">
               <li class="page-item @(Model.CurrentPage == 1? "disabled" : "")">
                   <!-- See how I change the page parameter? -->
                   <a href="@Url.Current(new { page = Model.CurrentPage - 1 })"
                       class="page-link" tabindex="-1">
                       &lt; Prev
                   </a>
               </li>

               @for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
               {
                   <li class="page-item @(i == Model.CurrentPage? "active" : "")">
                       <!-- See how I change the page parameter? -->
                       <a href="@Url.Current(new { page = i })" class="page-link">@i</a>
                   </li>
               }

               <li class="page-item @(Model.CurrentPage >= Model.EndPage? "disabled" : "")">
                   <!-- See how I change the page parameter? -->
                   <a href="@Url.Current(new { page = Model.CurrentPage + 1 })"
                       class="page-link" tabindex="-1">
                       Next &gt;
                   </a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

#### Extension method to get current URL

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace DL.SO.Framework.Mvc.Extensions
{
    public static class UrlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string Current(this IUrlHelper url, object routeValues)
        {
            // Convert new route values to a dictionary
            var newRouteData = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

            // Get current route data
            var currentRouteData = url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values;

            // Get current route query string and add them back to the new route
            var currentQuery = url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
            foreach (var param in currentQuery)
            {
                currentRouteData[param.Key] = param.Value;
            }

            // Merge new route data
            foreach (var item in newRouteData)
            {
                currentRouteData[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }

            return url.RouteUrl(currentRouteData);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say you have a `ProductController` that displays a list of products. Generally you have a view model for that page, and within that view model, you can have a list of products, as well as the `pager` class to represent the pagination.

#### View models

```
public class ProductListViewModel
{   
    public IList<ProductSummaryViewModel> Products { get; set; }
    public Pager Pager { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSummaryViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```
// I am just making this up. Not production ready
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public ProductController(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)
    {
        var vm = new ProductListViewModel
        {
            Products = new List<ProductSummaryViewModel>()
        };

        // Get products from database
        var products = _dbContext.Products
            .AsNoTracking();

        // Setup pagination
        vm.Pager = new Pager(products.Count(), page);

        var pagedProducts = products
            .Skip((vm.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * vm.Pager.PageSize)
            .Take(vm.Pager.PageSize)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var product in pagedProducts)
        {
            vm.Products.Add(new ProductSummaryViewModel
            {
               ProductId = product.Id,
               Name = product.Name
            });
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

#### Product list view - Index.cshtml

```
@model ProductListViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Products";
}

@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <!-- However you want to display your products -->
}

<!-- 
  -- This is how you generate the pagination. Just render the partial 
  -- with the pager model
  -->
@Html.Partial("_PagerPartial", Model.Pager)
```

#### Screenshot

[image: No fun without a screenshot to show how it works out?]

Answer (score 1):

Your action is not found on the controller when clicking "next" because the anchor is submitting a `get` request and the controller is configured to only accept `[HttpPost]` requests.

EDIT

In basic, I'd update your form to use `get`.
1. Update the form to use `method="get"`
2. Remove `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from the controller action
3. Update `Next` and `Previous` links to get current query string with modified page number (like below)

```
@{
        var existing = Url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value.ToString());
        existing["sortOrder"] = ViewData["CurrentSort"]?.ToString();
        existing["currentFilter"] = ViewData["CurrentFilter"]?.ToString();

        var previousData = new Dictionary<string, string>(existing);
        previousData["page"] = $"{Model.Results.PageIndex - 1}";

        var nextData = new Dictionary<string, string>(existing);
        nextData["page"] = $"{Model.Results.PageIndex + 1}";
    }

    <a asp-all-route-data="previousData" asp-action="GetResultList">Previous</a>
    <a asp-all-route-data="nextData" asp-action="GetResultList">Next</a>
```

Comment: What would be the best way to make the anchor tags send post vs get requests? Or would it be best to just remove the `[HttpPost]` tag from the controller method? It doesn't work when the httppost tag is removed.